# Is the nth root of a product of n terms used in place of the average anywhere?

Tags: products, average, radicals

In applied usage we typically take the average of values or terms which is done by summing them and dividing by the number of terms (for simple average):
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{n}$$

It dawned on me that the use of this form of mixing terms over some other form might be arbitrary.  Why not?:
$$\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i} $$
Is this equivalent to something that is already used extensively? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the **geometric mean** of the $a_i$. [Here is its Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean).

Comment: thanks for that! really interesting and was not taught in my studies.  In fact I don't think it is commonly used, but should be for a number of purposes.